# Is it possible to delete or update push notifications in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

It is necessary to display only the last 5 notifications. Accordingly, if the 6th appears, the first should be removed. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -2):

once you have published the message on the Firebase console, it is not possible to delete or update the notification.

You can check [Lifetime of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime) to know more how FCM notifications are being handled.